# How to customize system provided function for a special case?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching

## Background

I have a function, for example:

```
g=Function[{x,y},{x^2+y}]
```

And I want to compute $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$:

```
D[g[x,y],x]
```

which gives `2x`.

This is correct. But lets say I am not satisfied with this
for that the code `g[x,y]`(which is a function *application*) is not consistent with the math notation $g$ 
in the derivative $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.

What I want is to compute the derivative by

```
D[g,x]
```

(I understand the issue of notation abuse is subjective.
I just use this as an example to show what I want to do)

## What I have tried

I use a rule to match a function defined by `Function`,
and replace it with a "function application":

```
rule = HoldPattern[f : Function[vars_, _]] :> f @@ vars
```

Then I can write

```
D[g/.rule,x]
```

This works.

## Question

Is there any way to customize the `D` function for this special case
so that I do not have to write `/.rule`, while preserving its behavior for other cases?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Does `g=x^2+y; D[g,x]` count?

Comment: Also, how would you represent $\partial g(y,x)/\partial x$, or $\partial g(y+sin(x),x^{2+y})/\partial x$? The partial derivative notation only makes sense in a very limited range of applications. The more robust notation is differentiating with respect to positional arguments, which is achieved in Mathematica by `Derivative[1,0][g]` (=differentiate `g` with respect to its first argument).

Comment: @yohbs I want let `g` be function-like and callable through `g[a,b]`.

Comment: @yohbs Those two examples you gave can be perfectly expressed by `D[g[...,...],x]` since in those cases we apply the function first and then compute the derivative, which is consistent with `D`'s behavior. The suggestion of `Derivative` is what I want, except it requires more typing.

Comment: `D[g,x]` is not meaningful without knowing which argument of `g` `x` is.  The first?  The second? Etc. There is no way to know that.  In `Function[{x,y}, ...]`, `x` is just a placeholder that is not supposed to be visible from the outside. It is also subject to renaming by localization mechanism.  This is not notation abuse. It simply makes no sense, unless you declare that "$x$ is always the first variable".  This is what we actually do in math/physics: we agree on the variables first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set an `UpValue` on `Function` by `Unprotect`ing it.  This carries some risk as you are modifying a built-in symbol.  However, the pattern you are setting the `UpValue` for is incorrect syntax for `D` with `Function` which reduces the risk a bit.

```
Unprotect[Function];
Function /:
 D[HoldPattern[f : Function[vars_, __]], x_] := D[f @@ vars, x]
Protect[Function];
```

With

```
g = Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y];
```

Then

```
D[g, x]
```

> ```
> 2 x
> ```

```
D[g, y]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly need this override the standard method is using a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) that you'll disable inside the body of the function.

For example:

```
Unprotect[D];
Clear@D;
HoldPattern[D[Function[_, body_, ___], e___]] /; ! TrueQ[$inOveride] :=

    Block[{$inOveride = True},
   D[body, e]
   ];
Protect[D];
```

Then this works:

```
In[555]:= g = Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y];
D[g, x]

Out[556]= 2 x
```

Note that this could seriously damage the performance of any functionality that uses [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) in subtle ways.

When overriding built-ins it's also useful to know about [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Internal%60InheritedBlock), but your case really doesn't require that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want from the discussion in the comments, you can use the operator form of `Derivative`:

```
Dx=Derivative[1,0]
g = Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y];
Dx[g]
(*output: Function[{x, y}, {2 x}]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding built-ins you could create your own "function" head that will have desired behavior.

```
myFunction // ClearAll
myFunction // Attributes = HoldAll;
myFunction[vars_, body_]@args___ := Function[vars, body]@args
myFunction /: Derivative[varsDer_ /; MemberQ[Flatten@{varsDer}, Except@0], _]@myFunction = 0 &;
myFunction /: Derivative[_, 1]@myFunction = 1 &;
```

### Basic Examples

```
g = myFunction[{x, y}, x^2 + y]
(* myFunction[{x, y}, x^2 + y] *)
```

`g` is "callable":

```
g[a, b]
(* a^2 + b *)
```

and has expected derivatives, with implicit arguments:

```
D[g, x]
(* 2 x *)
D[g, y]
(* 1 *)
D[2 g + 5 x, x]
(* 5 + 4 x *)
```

and with explicit arguments:

```
D[g[x + 1, 7 x], x]
(* 7 + 2 (1 + x) *)
```

### Possible Issues

#### Nested scopes

Built-in `Function` is a scoping construct and other scoping constructs rename `Function`s variables if that's necessary:

```
g = With[{a = x}, Function[x, a x]]
g[k]
(* Function[x$, x x$] *)
(* k x *)
```

`myFunction` is not treated as scoping construct:

```
g = With[{a = x}, myFunction[x, a x]]
g[k]
(* myFunction[x, x x] *)
(* k^2 *)
```